# Arrow @ Tube does not work with Dynamic coordinates

Tags: bugs, front-end, graphics3d, dynamic

**Bug introduced in V10.0 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

> CASE:4063244

---

`Arrow @ Tube @ {Dynamic @ pt1, pt2}` does not seem to work. I'd expect the opposite since:

> Individual coordinates and lists of coordinates in tubes can be Dynamic objects
>
> - ref / Tube / Details and Options / last bullet point

> `Arrow[Tube[...]]` yields a 3D arrow based on a tube.
>
> - ref/ Arrow

Additionally `Arrow` supports `Dynamic` coordinates even though it is not explicitly stated in docs.

So why doesn't it work? Is there a workaround?

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   Orange, Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, Dynamic[x]}}],
   Green, Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, Dynamic[x]}}]
   },
  PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
 , {x, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Same story through V10.4-11.3

Comment: works as expected in v9.0

Comment: This is already broken in 10.0.2 by the way